# Can `getBoundingClientRect` return values in `rem`?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am using `rem`s for my CSS sizes and am also using `getBoundingClientRect` in javascript. `getBoundingClientRect` returns it's values in `px` by default. Is it possible to get it to return the values in `rem`s? It would make my code a little simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to convert it by dividing the pixels by the computed font size of the document:

```js
function convertPixelsToRem(px) {    
    return px / parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize.replace('px', ''));
}

console.log(convertPixelsToRem(div.getBoundingClientRect().width))
```

```css
#div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:grey;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

#div2{
  width:6.25rem;
  height:100px;
  background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought.